# How can I edit my looped ggplot code to produce a panel plot?

Tags: r

I have produced a large number of plots using a looped bit of ggplot code (below) which saves to disk as discrete images. I would like to produce panel plots showing several of these images as one.

Had I produced the plots manually, I would name them and then call par(mf) or similar to lay them out as desired. However, I can't find an alternative that works within (or after) my loop.

*

```
 graph <- function(MONTH_13, na.rm=TRUE) {
  SITE_LIST <- unique(MONTH_13$SITE_NUMB) 
  for(i in seq_along(SITE_LIST)){
    plotA <- ggplot(subset(MONTH_13, MONTH_13$SITE_NUMB==SITE_LIST[i]), aes(HR, OXYCONC, colour=VIAL_ID)) + 
      geom_point(size=2) + 
      geom_smooth(method="lm", se= FALSE)+
      labs(x="HR", y="OXY") + 
      labs(title= SITE_LIST[i]) + 
      theme(legend.position="top") +
      scale_color_brewer(name="VIAL #", palette="Dark2") + 
      ylim(0, 400) + 
      xlim(0, 200) 
    ggsave(plotA, file=paste('/Users/stafel/Desktop/MONTH_13/Site_', SITE_LIST[i], ".png", sep=''), scale=2)
    print(plotA)}}
graph(MONTH_13)
```

*

The above code will produce 13 plots. I want to put all 13 of these onto one panel plot image.

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: See this guide: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/egg/vignettes/Ecosystem.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grid.arrange`. Maybe you can have a look to this website :

http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/24-ggpubr-publication-ready-plots/81-ggplot2-easy-way-to-mix-multiple-graphs-on-the-same-page/

Comment: also check ggplot's `facet_wrap()` and `facet_grid()` options. very handy.